# Software which can generate natural human voices in different accents?

Tags: ios, audio, text-to-speech

I am making an interactive app for kids which uses human voices for interaction; I need a software which can generate audio files of natural human speech( like TTS) or any other way out. The App will be using audio files for commercial purpose, I am ready to buy or license the software.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [ispeech](http://www.ispeech.org/). It works with mobile apps. It's not free.

Answer (score 0):

[NeatSpeech](http://www.politepix.com/neatspeech/) can generate US and UK accent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TTSEngine.com](http://www.ttsengine.com) as a drop-in alternative to the Google or other TTS services. They give you 1000's of requests for free every month with a default voice.

They also sell custom voices, so if you would like your app to have a unique voice they can record an actor and build a TTS from the actor's voice. They'll give the custom voice exclusively to you for use in your apps.

Comment: this is good but it is an online service, do you know some desktop software which can do the same ?

Comment: Sure, Festival is free desktop software that can do it (little bit of work to install and setup though). A few big companies sell desktop software: Nuance, Acapela for example. Its generally very expensive ($10,000+), and expect the hardware requirements to be (for a good system) about 400MB and you'll need a very fast CPU.